# Scrapy working properly while debugging but not when running

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, pycharm

I'm facing a strage behavior from Scrapy. My code scrapes a page and yields items from it, and after yielding one item, I need to yield another `scrapy.Request` method to parse the first comments from that item, and in the `parseComments` method, I need to call itself again to paginate all the comments, but here's the problem: If I set a breakpoint right in `yield scrapy.Request` to call the first time `parseComments`, it works perfectly, but when I try to run without a breakpoint in that line, the scrapy just finishes and never reach that method. Why is this happening?

Here's my code:

```
class SpiderItemComments(InitSpider):
    name = "SpiderItems"
    headers_request = headers_request
    string_request = string_request
    string_request_paginator = string_request_paginator
    custom_settings = {
        'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy.dupefilters.BaseDupeFilter',
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 2,
        'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES': {
            'ScrapyItemComments.middlewares.CustomHeaderMiddleware': 543,
        },
        'ITEM_PIPELINES': {
            'ScrapyItemComments.pipelines.ScanPipeline': 300
        },
        'RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY': False,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1.5,
        'URLLENGTH_LIMIT': 99999,
        'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION': '2.7',
        'LOG_LEVEL': 'ERROR',
        'DUPEFILTER_DEBUG': True,
        'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': False
    }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.counter_paginate_items = 0
        self.counter_paginate_comments = 0
        self.cookies = "COOKIES"
        self.urlinicial = "InitialURL{}"
        self.paginadorurl = "PaginateURLItems"
        self.max_paginate_posts = 3
        self.max_paginate_comments = 3
        self.tempLista = []
        self.list_items = []
        self.list_comments = []
        super(SpiderItemComments, self).__init__()

    def init_request(self):
        dict_request = string_request.substitute("stringQuery")
        yield scrapy.Request(url=self.urlinicial.format("StringQUery"), callback=self.listitems,
                             cookies=self.cookies,
                             body=json.dumps(dict_request),
                             method="GET",
                             headers=self.headerrequest, errback=self.errorrequest)

    def listitems(self, response):
        list_items = json.loads(response.text)['data']['instructions'])
        if self.list_items:
            for value in self.listado_items:
                        # SOME CODE TO PARSE HTML TO ITEMS
                        yield item
                        dict_request = string_request_individual.substitute(focalitemId="StringQuery", controllerData=controllerData)
                        # HERE IS THE ISSUE, IF I DEBUG THIS LINE, THEN WORKS, BUT IF RUN NORMALLY
                        # JUST SKIP THE METHOD AND LISTCOMMENTS NEVER IS REACHED
                        yield scrapy.Request(url=self.accessIndividualitem.format(item['_id'], controllerData),
                                             callback=self.listcomments,
                                             cookies=self.cookies, body=json.dumps(dict_request),
                                             meta={"query": item['_id'],
                                                   "controllerData": controllerData},
                                             method='GET', headers=self.headerrequest, errback=self.errorrequest)
            cursor = ""
            if self.counter_paginate_items < self.max_paginate_posts:
                iterable = json.loads(response.text)['instructions']
                for j in iterable:
                    text = json.dumps(j)
                    if "cursorType" in text:
                        temporal = json.loads(text)['entries']
                        for k in temporal:
                            if "Bottom" in str(k):
                                cursor = k.get("content")['value']
            self.counter_paginate_items += 1
            self.logger.info("Paginate # {}".format(self.counter_paginate_items))
            if cursor:
                self.listado_items = []
                self.tempLista = []
                dict_request = string_request_paginator.substitute("StringQUery", cursor=cursor)
                yield scrapy.Request(url=self.paginadorurl.format("StringQuery", cursor),
                                     callback=self.listitems, cookies=self.cookies, body=json.dumps(dict_request),
                                     method='GET',
                                     headers=self.headerrequest, errback=self.errorrequest)
            else:
                raise CloseSpider("End of Scrapy")

        else:
            raise CloseSpider("End of Scrapy")

    def listcomments(self, response):
        list_entries_comment = json.loads(response.text)['data']['instructions'][0]['entries']
        self.listado_comments = list_entries_comment
        if self.list_comments:
            for value in self.listado_comments:
                # SOME EXTRA CODE
                yield comment
            cursor = ""
            if self.counter_paginate_comments < MAX_PAGINADO_COMMENTS:
                iterable = json.loads(response.text)['instructions']
                for j in iterable:
                    text = json.dumps(j)
                    if "cursorType" in text:
                        temporal = json.loads(text)['entries']
                        for k in temporal:
                            if "Bottom" in str(k):
                                cursor = k.get("content")['itemContent']['value']
                if cursor:
                    self.listado_comments = []
                    self.tempLista = []
                    dict_request = string_request_individual_paginator.substitute(itemId="Stringquery", cursor=cursor,
                                                                                  controllerData=controllerData)
                    yield scrapy.Request(url=self.paginateCommentsFromitem.format("StringQUery", cursor, controllerData),
                                         callback=self.listcomments, cookies=self.cookies, body=json.dumps(dict_request),
                                         method='GET', headers=self.headerrequest, errback=self.errorrequest)
                    self.counter_paginate_comments += 1
                else:
                    raise CloseSpider("End of Scrapy")
        else:
            raise CloseSpider("End of Scrapy")

    def errorrequest(self, failure):
        self.logger.error(
            "Error HTTP: " + repr(failure) + " HTTP STATUS: " + str(
                failure.value.response.status) + " WITH TEXT: " + failure.value.response.text)
```

While debugging I noticed Scrapy reaches CloseSpider before running `yield`.
And trying to call `listitems` itself just finishes scrapy, even while debuggin.
Hope you can help me.